# How to use quote inside LIKE jpql query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpql

So, I'm trying to write some custom JPQL query builder.
I have an endpoint something like:

```
/api/library/authors/search?query=test tested
```

On service layer this `query` param will be transformed to smth like this JPQL query:

```
SELECT t FROM Author t WHERE t.fullName LIKE '%test tested%' 
     OR t.firstName  LIKE '%test%' 
     OR t.firstName  LIKE '%tested%' 
     OR t.secondName LIKE '%test%' 
     OR t.secondName LIKE '%tested%'
```

It works pretty good for me but, it is possible that `firstName` or `secondName` table columns will contain values with quote `'` like `O'Hara`. Then it won't work.

```
/api/library/authors/search?query=Tes O'Ha
```

So, I tried to replace `'` to double quotes `"` in query to smth like this:

```
SELECT t FROM Author t WHERE t.fullName LIKE "%Tes O'Ha%" 
     OR t.firstName  LIKE "%Tes%" 
     OR t.firstName  LIKE "%O'Ha%" 
     OR t.secondName LIKE "%Tes%" 
     OR t.secondName LIKE "%O'Ha%"
```

and I got an exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"'
```

I also tried to replace `'` on `\'` and `"` on `\"`. All it not works and throws me an exception...

I'm executing this queries using EntityManager:

```
@Repository
public class SearchFor {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List execute(String query) {
        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }      
}
```

How can I search for value that contains single quote `'`?

Comment: Did you tried  escaping ***LIKE "%Tes O\'Ha%" *** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
And... it is pretty simple. It is needed just to double the quote symbol like `''`

And the JPQL query will looks like:

```
SELECT t FROM Author t WHERE t.fullName LIKE '%Tes O''Ha%' 
    OR t.firstName  LIKE '%Tes%' 
    OR t.firstName  LIKE '%O''Ha%' 
    OR t.secondName LIKE '%Tes%' 
    OR t.secondName LIKE '%O''Ha%'
```

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use indexed or named parameters for your query creation. That would solve your issue as it would automatically escape any command characters.

Something like this:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM TestEntity t WHERE t.fullName LIKE :fullName " 
                + "OR t.firstName  LIKE :firstName " 
                + "OR t.firstName  LIKE :lastName " 
                + "OR t.lastName LIKE :firstName " 
                + "OR t.lastName LIKE :lastName") 
                .setParameter("firstName", firstName) 
                .setParameter("lastName", lastName) 
                .setParameter("fullName", fullName)
                .getResultList();
```

I assume you get your firstName, lastName, fullName from the method parameter in the service layer.

Also, your current implementation makes your app vulnerable to SQL/JPQL attacks, because the user can inject malicious code through the REST endpoint.

More about SQL injection: 
https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection

Query creation with named and indexed parameters:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-query-parameters

Comment: It will not work in my case. The sql query depend from the count of words in searched query. It isn't a static String where I can pass different parameters. The count of OR statements can be different in two calls and the queryalways changing dynamiclly

Comment: I see. You could check out CriteriaQuery API with that, you can really create dynamic queries: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria.